# How to handle CSV columns with value "NULL" as real NULL on the destination using Informatica Data Engineering?

Tags: etl, informatica, data-transform

Is there any option to specify to Informatica that is should consider the text "NULL" on any text file column as real NULL values?

I would want to believe that I would not be required to perform a comparison transformation on each and every column.

The file is **NOT** a fixed-width delimited.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to make Informatica treat text as null. Have you tried replacing the text values so that there would be no falue in the row for such column?

Comment: The problem comes when you have CSV with 100s columns :)
Other tools have options to either consider the text NULL as real nulls or as Text.
I find weird that Informatica does not.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a CSV file - it makes things quite simple - change the input type to `Command` as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/workflow-basics-guide/sources/working-with-file-sources/configuring-source-properties.html) and use sed to read the file:

```
sed 's/NULL//' sed_test.csv
```

Here's a sample file that I've created. Below's the content of the file displaed by `$ head sed_test.csv` command:

```
George Washington,NULL,NULL, 1789-1797
John Adams,NULL,NULL, 1797-1801
Thomas Jefferson,NULL,NULL, 1801-1809
James Madison,NULL,NULL, 1809-1817
James Monroe,NULL,NULL, 1817-1825
John Quincy Adams,NULL,NULL, 1825-1829
Andrew Jackson,NULL,NULL, 1829-1837
Martin Van Buren,NULL,NULL, 1837-1841
William Henry Harrison,NULL,NULL, 1841
John Tyler,NULL,NULL, 1841-1845
```

Now, here's the same using `sed 's/NULL//g' sed_test.csv | head`:

```
George Washington,,, 1789-1797
John Adams,,, 1797-1801
Thomas Jefferson,,, 1801-1809
James Madison,,, 1809-1817
James Monroe,,, 1817-1825
John Quincy Adams,,, 1825-1829
Andrew Jackson,,, 1829-1837
Martin Van Buren,,, 1837-1841
William Henry Harrison,,,
```

As you see, the columns are there, values are not there anymore.